# How to divide 2 integers without using / operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I divide two integers without using the `/` operator?

Thank you so much for the help in advance.
I will explain why this question -i just get hired and of course they test me with this school question.
Thank you
I make in sql server using / divide operator in 2 ways in few minutes but without / i really don t know.
Thank you

Comment: What's the premise for this requirement, and why have you tagged MySql, a completely different database platform from the one(s) you ask about?

Comment: Why such a strange need? What is the reason?

Comment: What's the expected result of 20 divided by 3? Do you want 6.66666667, or 6, or 7?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment or interview question. Please show us what you have tried to far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok i will answer why do i put MySQL. Because first i put sql and suggest me to put also something else. That s way i put mysql.i need in sql server.please.i know is a strange request and i apologize and yes in this for 20 divided by 3 i need 6.6666 etc. Thank you

Comment: select  (cast(cast(cu_proc as float) / cast(cate as float) as decimal(4,2)))*1.0 as procent .this is the final line but is shoud be without / operator.Thank you

Comment: `20 / 3` -> `exp(log(20) - log(3))`, will work for positive integers.

Comment: I do not understand why this requirement would be worth the time if you have RDBMS you can use the operators, which means it can only be an intellectual exercise, in which case You should, respectfully solve it Yourself or explain the necessity for at least myself also to want to spend the time to help. i think @Stu pointed in the right direction. A tedious usage of modulus and remainder operations can solve it also for example.

Comment: I just get hired and of course they test me with this question.

Comment: And now they are checking the Stackoverflow questions. Do you think this is a good or bad idea?

Comment: This feels like a maths question, not a SQL question, if I am honest. Once you've worked out how to do division with using division, then you can work out how to implement that.

Comment: 1/x= power(x,-1) …. `select 2./-3, 2*power(cast(-3 as float),-1);`

Comment: Your solution lptr  -select 2./-3, 2*power(cast(-3 as float),-1) is work.thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sign(a*b) * exp(log(abs(a)) - log(abs(b)))
```

Comment: i will try this.thank you so much

Comment: is working.many many thanks

Comment: i ve try to mark your answer because it works but i can t because i need 15 reputation. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In MS Sql Server the division of an integer by an integer will return an integer.

A commonly used trick is to multiply the first integer by 1.0

```
1.0*IntColumn1 / IntColumn2 AS FractionResult
```

Simple test to demonstrate

> ```
> select 5/2 as result1, 1.0*5/2 as result2;
> ```

| result1 | result2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2.500000 |

Comment: OP for some strange reason wants "_without using the / operator_"

Comment: Yes, but in the comments it just shows he doesn't want an INT as result.